# Do I set TripleBuffer "1" or "true" in xorg.conf?

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I am trying to figure out how to enable Triple Buffering. Google says I need to add a line to my xorg.conf file, but every site I've gone to said to use "1" or "true". Does it matter which one I use?

Comment: Read `man xorg.conf`, there's the answer. ("1" and "true" are interpreted the same for boolean options.)

Comment: @edwin Sounds like you should post that as an answer... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the sames as with every other option for (Nvidia's) proprietary drivers. Go to the [**Nvidia Unix driver page**](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html) and pick the version you installed. Go to the **Additional Information** tab and click the **Readme** link, which will lead you to **NVIDIA Accelerated Linux Graphics Driver README and Installation Guide** for the selected version. Triplebuffer and other options are in [**Appendix B. X Config Options**](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/319.32/README/xconfigoptions.html).

[image]